# Remove unwanted margin due to line-break in HTML

Tags: css, html

I get an unwanted margin between `block1` and `block2` with `display: inline-block` style. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SbUwt/).

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="innercontainer">
        <div id="block1">
            block1
        </div>
        <div id="block2">
            block2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#container {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#innercontainer {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#block1, #block2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00f;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The margin disappears when I change the HTML to this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="innercontainer">
        <div id="block1">
            block1
        </div><div id="block2">
            block2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="innercontainer">
        <div id="block1">
            block1
        </div><!--
     --><div id="block2">
            block2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

While I prefer the latter, I still do wonder if anyone knows a solution so I can use the original HTML, but no whitespace shows up in `innercontainer`. Also note that I want to avoid setting `float: left;` on both `block1` and `block2` or making them floating by `position: absolute|relative` because that generates other problems in my layout. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Ok, so I had more trouble with my layout. When I added an image to block1, the whole block moved down, very strange (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbKMJ/)). I am now using `float: left` and will have to figure out how I can add a div that consumes the free-space on the right.

Comment: What are other problems when floating?

Comment: the remaining space in innercontainer on the right should be filled with a 'content' div.

Comment: Could you fix widths to percentage? ie #block1 25% #block2 25% and new div 50%

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Thanks for the suggestions, but it should be pixels, both divs contain some images of that particular width.

Comment: For anyone getting here anno 2021+: you should now use `display: grid` (CSS grid layout) or `display: flex` (CSS flexbox) to avoid this nonsense. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this part of css :

```
#block1, #block2 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color: #00f;
    height: 200px;
}
```

When you are inline, spaces take space!

**EDIT :**

To be safe change this part of HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="innercontainer">
        <div id="block1">
            block1
        </div>
        <div id="block2">
            block2
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your quote "When you are inline, spaces take space!" made me think: what if I set `font-size: 0px` on `innercontainer` and reset the correct `font-size` in `block1` and `block2`, and this actually fixes it! Don't know if it's cross-browser. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Za4AE/)

Comment: Ok, so I had more trouble with my layout. When I added an image to block1, the whole block moved down, very strange :) I am now using `float: left` and will have to figure out how I can add a div that consumes the free-space on the right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `display: inline-block;`. You need to close gap between  tags like you mention. Because The  it self are treated as inline-elements also. When you have a space or line-break between two tags would create a gap between them.

You can fix this by set font-size of a surrounding container to 0 and set them back in child node.

```
#innercontainer {
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;

  font-size: 0px;

}
#block1, #block2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #00f;
    height: 200px;

  font-size: 15px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SbUwt/27/

Comment: Setting the font-size to 0 was also something I figured out, but I had even more issues. When I added an image to block1, the block moved down for an unknown reason. Seems like `float: left` is the only way out to get 2 divs sticking togetter.